# How to create a magnifying glass in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Does anyone know how can i achieve the magnifying glass effect in React Native? I keep searching for a solution to implement this for a few days already but nothing came up..

Example:
[image]

Comment: use [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-canvas) take a snapshot of your screen, and then display a small popup which listens to the touch position

Comment: Please check this link 
https://medium.com/how-to-react/create-image-magnifying-effect-in-reactjs-9823702bcdfd

Comment: @Soheb unfortunately that's a ReactJS solution.. I am developing a mobile app on React Native

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen That's a solution I also thought about but how can you achieve the 'real-time' effect using this approach?

Comment: its not that complicated